# How to pass environment variables in angular application with docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, angular6, yaml, volume

I m running my Angular 6 application as a Kubernetes pod/container. In this Angular app, I try to access a JSON config-object, to load my environment variables.

I have used volume to read the config map and volume mount to create a config json file.

My service is throwing a `503` error IF I include the volume creation code in my yaml file.

The pods are in running mode when seen in logs.

Code snippet of my deployment yaml file:

```
  apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "client-onboard.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "client-onboard.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "client-onboard.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "client-onboard.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "client-onboard.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          volumeMounts:
          - name: env-vars
            mountPath: usr/share/nginx/html/config/env-vars.json
      volumes:
        - name: env-vars
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-configmap
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

I am using nginx server for this.

Comment: is your pod in error status?

Comment: no pod is in running status but while browsing the application doesn't get loaded and end up throwing 503 service unavailable error.

Answer (score 1):

**For creating a file you need to use subPath.The value of the subPath must match the “key” of the ConfigMap. In the below example the key and subPath is config.yaml.**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: sherlock-config
  namespace: default
data:
  config.yaml: |
    namespaces:
      - default
    labels:
      - "app"
      - "owner"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /etc/config/" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config/config.yaml
        subPath: config.yaml
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: sherlock-config
  restartPolicy: Never
```

kubectl describe cm sherlock-config

```
Name:         sherlock-config
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"config.yaml":"namespaces:\n  - default\nlabels:\n  - \"app\"\n  - \"owner\"\n"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":...

Data
====
config.yaml: <------ This is the key
----
namespaces:
  - default
labels:
  - "app"
  - "owner"

Events:  <none>
```

Comment: I want to create a file named env-var.JSON which can be readable by my angular application to get environment specific values  from it. With this its creating the directory instead of file. Something like this.
https://carlos.mendible.com/2019/02/10/kubernetes-mount-file-pod-with-configmap/

Comment: File got created with the content but service is still not up and throwing 503 error. Is it because the kind for me is Deployment and you have mentioned it Pod?

Comment: you get error 503 when you access it via nginx ingress? What happenes when you access it via clusteip from inside the cluster?